# Difference between Travel vs migrate

Tags: differences, american-english

I would like to ask what is the difference between travel and migrate?.

I have read definitions of both and they seem to me similar (are they?)
from what i have read migrate and travel both can be said to someone who move from region to another within the same country or move across borders while travel seem to mean the same thing as well

here are some definitions from the american heritage dictionary
traveler : "One who or that which travels in any way; one who makes a journey, or who is on his way from place to place"

migrant: "An organism ... that moves from one region to another (as for breeding) or that has established itself in an area where it previously did not exist."
so a migrant can also be someone moving within the same country. Both terms involve moving but can someone clarify the differences?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a dictionary?

Comment: 'Migrate' is _specifically_ used of (1) animals that regularly move to another region of the world for part of the year, and (2) people who go to live in another country or region for economic reasons. 'Travel' can refer to any journey. A dictionary should have made this clear.

Comment: You have cherry-picked the definition in the AHD. You should read the others and note that all migrants are travellers (or have travelled) but not all travellers are migrants.

Comment: Migrants from relatively rich countries, especially if the stay is relatively long-term but considered temporary, may prefer the term "ex-patriot" (ex-pat).

Comment: Do you know what an "organism" is in the definition you quote?